# Php and Ajax listener for a remote response

Tags: jquery, ajax, listener

I need a guidance on how to achieve this:

User comes to www.mysite.com/submit.php and fill out the form where they need to enter a phone number (for verification purposes) and what I want to happen is when form is submitted:

1. Popup - or some overlay that will tell them... PLEASE WAIT FOR A CALL (and will prevent them from clicking links in the background)
2. In the background request is sent to remote server that will do the call and ask them to enter a pin once they answer the phone.
3. I will get a response from server in GET format like: www.mysite.com/submit.php?pincheck=success
4. Now based on ?pincheck (success or failed) I want to to redirect them to corresponding pages (success.php  or  failed.php)

Any ideas how to do this and what to use ? Ajax.. Jquery ???

Answer (score 0):

1-  the overlay with a modal will accomplish part 1, but they can always just navigate away from your site with a URL.

2-  Depends if the form submits.  You can take the data, JSONify it, then ajax request which would do the same thing without the whole jumping around thing.

3- This would be accomplished by waiting till the user inputs stuff.  You can use asp.net to have a form ping the server on input and do a postback, but what i would do is when you do the AJAX request from 2, return a unique ID relavent to the user (primary key in a db).  When the user enters the secret phrase, it will submit a second form with the pinn and the hidden field user data.  (Hint:  You will want a timestamp on the db table so that way it is usable for only 15 minutes within the calls time.

4- if you are using AJAX which i assume you are for part 3, you can take the response text and check for "1" or "0".   If 1, redirect to success, otherwise to the begining.

I dont know if you want code samples, but just looking at this, using ajax... it will be 1  page client side, with 2 different server pages.  If you use ASP.NET, it is accomplished with 1 page.

Other thing to note:  I do not know how the server would make calls, so that you might want to look into.  I know you can send texts and such from a webserver, i wasnt sure about automated phone calls though.

Naturally, this will require a a db, a server script or 2, and 1 front end.  Pretty straight forward.  Also, as a hint, for the modal on the page, you should make sure there is some thing to make them know that the server is going to call them, a gif, or image is simple enough, with the input tag at the bottom and a submit anchor tag.

Edit: With the exception of the call, I would say, this is about 2 hours of programming if you are fast.  4 if soso, 6 if you have no idea what you are doing. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointers. I think I will be using Ajax (never did before, so... good time to learn, yea :)  Ayway the thing is actually very simple with this phone system: I send a command to server via GET... so it's in this format: www.verify.com?phone=2121234123&callback=http//www.mysite.com/submit.php   and I get response also in GET format: www.mysite.com/submit.php?pincheck=success  Now the trick is just to wait for remote response if success or failed and in the meanwhile just don't let users click on links on site (so not to navigate away)... yes - they can always close, but that's OK !

Comment: oh, as for a listener.... thats what the db is for.   Have a table that has a PK, data, and timestamp, and if the CURRENT - timestamp > 30 mintes, remove the row from the table.  :)